# Install ruby on rails on VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I managed to install it locally without any problem but on my VPN I can't follow the guide at all. Execution stops at gem install rails -v 3.2.3 with an error that I can't seem to fix after googling for hours.

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.3
========================================
Fetching: i18n-0.6.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: multi_json-1.3.6.gem (100%)
Fetching: activesupport-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: builder-3.0.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: activemodel-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-1.4.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-cache-1.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-test-0.6.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: journey-1.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: hike-1.2.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: tilt-1.3.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: sprockets-2.1.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: erubis-2.7.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionpack-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: arel-3.0.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: tzinfo-0.3.33.gem (100%)
Fetching: activerecord-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: activeresource-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: mime-types-1.19.gem (100%)
Fetching: polyglot-0.3.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: treetop-1.4.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: mail-2.4.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionmailer-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: thor-0.14.6.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-ssl-1.3.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: json-1.7.4.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/app-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
generator.c: In function 'isArrayOrObject':
generator.c:867:5: warning: suggest parentheses around '&&' within '||'
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so

make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 generator.so /home/app-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.4/lib/json/ext
installing default generator libraries


Gem files will remain installed in /home/app-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/app-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.4/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

The guide I'm using: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/
I tried other guides as well. Same error pops out. Any ideas?

Comment: add /home/app-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.4/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Comment: what gcc (`ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["CC"]'`) and version (`$(ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["CC"]') --version`) did you used to compile your ruby?

Comment: Have you tried installig `apt-get install ruby1.9.3-dev`?